# How to change Java's byte to long in Swift

Tags: java, swift, byte

I am porting Android app written in Java to iOS in Swift.
I have to store byte data into long variable.

Here's what I've done and failed.

In Java,

```
public class TEST {
    public long mode_time;

    public void setData(byte[] raw) {
        mode_time = (long)((raw[3] << 24 |  (raw[2] << 16) | (raw[1] << 8) | (raw[0] << 0));
    }
}
```

My attempt in Swift,

```
class TEST {
    var mode_time : Int = 0

    func setData(raw : [UInt8]) {
        mode_time = Int(raw[3] << 24 |  raw[2] << 16 | raw[1] << 8 | raw[0] << 0)
    }
}
```

And Xcode says

> "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
>    time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions."

Does anyone can let me know right expression?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `Byte` type in Swift.

Comment: @MartinR Oh.. you're right, Byte is actually UInt8. After I podded 'SwiftySocket', I could use Byte as UInt8. I just edited [Byte] to [UInt8].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Byte` is a type alias for `UInt8`: You have to convert the bytes to `Int` *before* shifting the values to the left, otherwise the result can overflow. This also helps the compiler to compile the expression successfully:

```
func setData(raw : [Byte]) {
    mode_time = Int(raw[3] << 24) | Int(raw[2] << 16) | Int(raw[1] << 8) | Int(raw[0] << 0)
}
```

Note also that the Swift `Int` type is platform dependent, it can be a 32-bit or a 64-bit integer, and on a 32-bit platform the above code an overflow if the result exceeds the maximal value of a signed integer. You might want to use `UInt`, `UInt32`, or `Int64` instead. The latter is a  64-bit integer on all platforms, like Java's `long`.

An alternative implementation is

```
func setData(raw : [Byte]) {
    mode_time = raw.reversed().reduce(Int(0)) { ($0 << 8) + Int($1) }
}
```

if you don't feed more bytes than what fits into an `Int`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Error is gone and successfully build.